# how to iterate through hashmap<String ArrayList<String>> and create xml file name with key String and nodes from arraylist

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I have a xml file which i read and inserted certain values into hasmap .   ex: key-apple, value:111,USD,iphone4

I need to Iterate through keys and make separate xml files for each diferent name and insert into each file values from array list:

from above example it would look like:

```
<products>
             <product>
                   <price>111</price>
                    <currency>USD</currency>
                    <type>iphone4</type>
             <product>
        <products>
```

BELOW IS MY CODE SO FAR>>>>>

```
      https://pastebin.com/unqZjSRc
```

I have a problem with the last part in which i have to create the xml...according to values in array...can anyone suggest an idea?

output from hashmap is :

```
    Sony

           Sony 54.6" (Diag) Xbr Hx929 Internet Tv
           00027242816657
           2999.99
           USD
           2343
           Sony NWZ-E464 8GB E Series Walkman Video MP3 Player Blue
           00027242831438
           91.99
           USD
           2343
    Apple

           Apple iPad 2 with Wi-Fi 16GB - iOS 5 - Black
           00885909464517
           399.0
           USD
           2343
           Apple MacBook Air A 11.6" Mac OS X v10.7 Lion MacBook
           00885909464043
           1149.0
           USD
           2344
    Panasonic

           Panasonic TC-L47E50 47" Smart TV Viera E50 Series LED HDTV
           00885170076471
           999.99
           USD
           2344
```

Meanwhile i used:

```
    package pss;
    import java.util.*;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;


    //@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name="Products")
    //@XmlSeeAlso({ArrayList.class})
    class ProdsList {

         @XmlElement(name="Product")
         ArrayList<String>  prods;

         public ProdsList(){
             prods=new ArrayList<String>();
         }
         public ProdsList(ArrayList<String> value){
                prods=new ArrayList<String>(value);
            }
         public ArrayList<String> getProducts() {
             return prods;
         }

         public void setProducts(ArrayList<String> prods) {
             this.prods = prods;
         }
    }
```

with the code:

```
                try {

                    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProdsList.class);
                    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

                    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                  Set setOfKeys = hashmap.keySet();
                  Iterator iterator = setOfKeys.iterator();
                 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                 String keys = (String) iterator.next();
                 String filename= keys+last2digits+".xml";
                 File file = new File(filename);
                  ArrayList<String> value = hashmap.get(keys);
                  jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new ProdsList(value), file);
                  jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new ProdsList(value), System.out);
                 }
                  } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Example of one output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
    <Product>Apple iPad 2 with Wi-Fi 16GB - iOS 5 - Black</Product>
    <Product>00885909464517</Product>
    <Product>399.0</Product>
    <Product>USD</Product>
    <Product>2343</Product>
    <Product>Apple MacBook Air A 11.6" Mac OS X v10.7 Lion MacBook</Product>
    <Product>00885909464043</Product>
    <Product>1149.0</Product>
    <Product>USD</Product>
    <Product>2344</Product>
    <products>Apple iPad 2 with Wi-Fi 16GB - iOS 5 - Black</products>
    <products>00885909464517</products>
    <products>399.0</products>
    <products>USD</products>
    <products>2343</products>
    <products>Apple MacBook Air A 11.6" Mac OS X v10.7 Lion MacBook</products>
    <products>00885909464043</products>
    <products>1149.0</products>
    <products>USD</products>
    <products>2344</products>
</Products>
```

I'm using now:  https://pastebin.com/irHtbWzi

amd still get the :

```
Sony_54_6___Diag__Xbr_Hx929_Internet_Tv
00027242816657
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.
```

When i parse the first one it works but for the second it won't

Comment: In your first example, the key **apple** does not appear in the XML. I guess it should, right?

Comment: yess, it should also have a tag  <supplier>apple</supplier>          ...i.m now focusing on the second exemple, the JAXB one as I manged at least to get some xmls from it, i need to figure out the @xmlroot element etc..

Comment: my question is how do i make each element of the arraylist have its own tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm not sure it's the end of the road, but the output I got is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Supplier>Apple</Supplier>
    <Price>10.5</Price>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Type>MacBook</Type>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Supplier>NOKIA</Supplier>
    <Price>12.5</Price>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Type>PHONE</Type>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Class **Product**:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class Product {

  @XmlElement(name="Supplier")
  private String supplier;

  @XmlElement(name="Price")
  private String price;

  @XmlElement(name="Currency")
  private String currency;

  @XmlElement(name="Type")
  private String type;

  public Product() {

  }

  public Product(String supplier, String price, String currency, String type) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.price = price;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

Class **ProductList**:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static javax.xml.bind.JAXB.marshal;

@XmlRootElement(name="Products")
public class ProdsList {

  @XmlElement(name="Product")
  private ArrayList<Product> prods;

  public ProdsList() {}

  public ProdsList(ArrayList<Product> value){
    prods = value;
  }

  public ArrayList<Product> getProd() {
    return prods;
  }

  public void setProducts(ArrayList<Product> prod) {
    this.prods = prod;
  }
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Product p1 = new Product("Apple", "10.5", "USD", "MacBook");
  Product p2 = new Product("NOKIA", "12.5", "USD", "PHONE");
  ArrayList<Product> a = new ArrayList<>();
  a.add(p1);
  a.add(p2);
  ProdsList l = new ProdsList(a);

  marshal(l, System.out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out eventually i should have done marshalling an d unmarshalling with JAXB, not just the writting to xml..your answer is still helpfull even though i send the project in the 65% correct state I had it